# SQL procedure execution order

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a system set up with a batch execution of a stored procedure 10 times.

```html
exec procedure 1
exec procedure 2
exec procedure 3
exec procedure 4
...
exec procedure 10
```

The procedure is designed to accumulate a running total based on the ID of the record in a target table.

When I run that batch I will get results that are out of sync.  The running total should just be the running total of the previous row, plus the value of the current row.

When I run the same batch with a GO statement in between each, it takes much longer to run, but executes correctly.

Is there any kind of hint (like "MAXDOP 1") that can be done in this situation to force the procedures to execute and complete in order without going out of sync?

I should add that the stored procedure being called, calls several procedures itself.  If that has any bearing on a solution.

Comment: Maybe editing the procedure itself would be better? It is hard to say without knowing more of what is going on

Comment: Obviously, the execution of the procedures gets parallelized by default, so they finish quickly, but their order appears chaotic.  And obviously, inserting GO in between ensures that they will be executed in order, which is what you want, but then there will be no parallelism, so they will take longer to run.  Please choose either order or speed, you can't have both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stored Procedure - forcing execution order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682960/stored-procedure-forcing-execution-order)

Comment: The only parallelism that SQL Server lets you take advantage of from a single connection is parallelism within the execution of a *single* statement. If you execute 10 procedures then each one will only start after the previous one finishes. Separate statements within the stored procedures also each run to completion before the next statement runs. Whatever you were seeing, it wasn't parallelism *across* statements or stored procedures.

Comment: Yes, I was mistaken in my original assessment.  It turns out the issue was a flaw in the logic for a tie-break rule when dates were the same, which was causing a later record to have the running total updated before its dependent record.

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit more testing on this, and it looks like my initial thoughts were incorrect.  I did several tests with batches using GO statements, and even then, only a few records in the batch would have their running balances updated, but the remaining would stay out of sync.  It looks like when I did my initial tests, the first 10 records updated properly, but I didn't notice anything else in that section since the rest of the values were already correct until a later section of the data set.

This looks like it is an issue internal to the procedure, not repeated execution of the procedure.  The weird part is that we never experienced this issue on a single-core system which is what still leaves to me thinking this is a parallelism issue, but most likely internal to the procedure.

Sorry for wasting your time.